# three.js instanceMatrix position ignores Z axis

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to make a three.js scene with a gridded floor similar to a chess board.
The code I have manages to alter the colors of the tiles, but somehow the Z axis movement is ignored.
This is the code of the function:
`addFloor()
{

```
    const lightColor = new THREE.Color(0xB8D0D9);
    const darkColor = new THREE.Color(0xADC4CC);

    const cellSize = 1000;
    const countXY = 1000;
    const count = countXY*countXY;
    const xy0 = 0;

    const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( cellSize,cellSize,cellSize );            // Create plane Geometry as template
    const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {side: THREE.DoubleSide, opacity:0.6, depthWrite: false} );  // Create colored material

    const floor = new THREE.InstancedMesh(geometry, material, countXY);  // Create instanced mesh of template, one for each pixel

    let color;
    let idX = 0;
    let idZ = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        idX = i % countXY;
        idZ = Math.floor(i / countXY);
        color = (idX + idZ) % 2 === 0 ? lightColor : darkColor;
        
        const pos = new Vector3(
            xy0 + idX * cellSize,
            0,
            xy0 + idZ*cellSize
        );

        const m = new THREE.Matrix4();
        m.makeTranslation(pos.x, pos.y, pos.z);

        floor.setMatrixAt(i, m);
        floor.setColorAt(i, color);
    }
    floor.instanceColor.needsUpdate = true;
    floor.instanceMatrix.needsUpdate = true;

    this.add(floor);
}`
```

The class this function is in inherits from THREE.Scene, so 'this' is of type Scene.

If I use the variable idX instead of idZ in the pos Vector, the tiles align themselves on a diagonal like they should in that case.
I thought it might be that the Math.floor does not correctly round down, but console.log shows it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found the answer.
The problem was with creating the InstancedMesh. I used `new THREE.InstancedMesh(geometry, material, countXY);`. The correct way would have been to use `new THREE.InstancedMesh(geometry, material, count);`.

In the first example, I used countXY, which is the dimensions of the grid. The number of tiles is saved in count, so I should have used that.